# htmlspecialchars decode php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I posted some inputs with special characters.
Here are some input example i'm trying to insert into db:

```
<input type='text' name='address' value ='P. 34/1 Ap. 4/4 Rome, "xxx" street'>
<input type='text' name='detail' value ='VAT Reg. No'>
```

I inserted the inputs in db like these:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']);
htmlspecialchars($_POST['detail']);

$db->sql_query(
    "INSERT INTO company SET 
        option_type=1, 
        option_name='". htmlspecialchars($address)."', 
        option_value='". htmlspecialchars($detail)."'"
);
```

I retrieved the records:

```
<input type="text" value="htmlspecialchars_decode($rows['address'])"> 
<input type="text" value="htmlspecialchars_decode($rows['detail'])">
```

This is ok till now, the values are correctly inserted like:

adress: `P. 34/1 Ap. 4/4 Rome, quot;xxxquot; street`

detail: `VAT Reg. No`

But the problem is when i read them from DB, it displays nothing. I tried to  use `htmlspecialchars_decode` and `htmlentities()` but i'm not getting all characters correctly displayed.

When i used htmlspecialchars_decode() to display the values, only the `detail` value isn't displayed at all, the address is ok.

Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you show how you insert and retrieve records?

Comment: Escape correctly for the correct occasion! [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: I inserted the records:
`$db->sql_query("INSERT INTO company SET option_type=1, option_name='". htmlspecialchars($address)."', option_value='". htmlspecialchars($detail)."'");`


I retrieved the records:
`<input type="text" value="htmlspecialchars_decode($rows['address'])">
<input type="text" value="htmlspecialchars_decode($rows['detail'])">`

Comment: what does view source show after rendering

Comment: When you decode special characters and render to the browser, you will get busted html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to convert special characters to insert thos strings into the database. You need to escape it using something like real_escape_string though.

You should only really use htmlspecialchars and such on output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using [mysqli](http://de3.php.net/mysqli), not mysql. And you should definitely look at [prepared statements](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), that should save a lot of hazzle and close even more potential security holes. And as euantorano said, no need to escape the strings. As a suggestion, add O'Reilly to your test-cases - when that saves fine, you're close ;)